Is $\ell^\infty({\mathbb N})\otimes\ell^\infty({\mathbb N})$ weakly dense in $\ell^\infty({\mathbb N}\times{\mathbb N})$?
There is a natural embedding $\Phi$ of the (algebraic) tensor product $\ell^\infty({\mathbb N})\otimes\ell^\infty({\mathbb N})$ into the Banach space $\ell^\infty({\mathbb N}\times{\mathbb N})$ given by
$$\big(\Phi(x\otimes y)\big)_{(n,m)}=x_n\cdot y_m$$
on elementary tensors and extended using linearity.

Question: Is the image of $\Phi$ dense with respect to the weak
topology?

The fact that I can not answer it gives me the nagging suspicion that the answer is negative, but I'm hoping that it is positive.
It's easy to see that the image of $\Phi$ is not dense in norm; indeed its norm closure will not contain the vector $x_{n,m}=1_{n=m}$.
On the other hand, as point out by Ben Grossmann in the comments, the image of $\Phi$ is dense in the weak$^*$ topology.
I also believe that the restriction of $\Phi$ to $\ell^p({\mathbb N})\otimes\ell^p({\mathbb N})$ is dense in $\ell^p({\mathbb N}\times{\mathbb N})$ for every $1\leq p<\infty$, even in norm.

I assume the case $\ell^{\infty}$ case is hard because it's dual is not so nice.

I don't know if this is at all a helpful observation, but if we identify $\ell^\infty$ with $(\ell^1)^*$, then we do have density relative to the weak* topology

@BenGrossmann Good point!

@MartinBrandenburg Right, as Ben pointed out if the weak topology were the same as the weak$^*$ topology this would be relatively easy.

If by weak topology you meant Banach weak topology, then no. The range of $\Phi$ is a subspace, so by Hahn-Banach, it is weakly dense iff it is norm-dense, and you’ve already observed it is not norm-dense.

@DavidGao Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you for pointing that out; if you write it as an answer I'll acept it.

As requested by the OP, here is my comment, re-organized into an answer:
By Hahn-Banach, the closure of a convex subset under the weak topology coincides with its closure under the norm topology. In particular, since the range of $\Phi$ is a linear subspace, it is weakly dense iff it is norm-dense. As the OP has already observed, the range of $\Phi$ is not norm-dense, so it is not weakly dense either.
